# Highcharts Javascript - Synchronize Chart and Table not working - Cant read property cell of undefined

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Trying to synchronize my highchart with my table. I have followed the steps this page https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/synchronize-selection-bi-directionally-between-chart-and-table/
and the github script below which is how they have done it: https://github.com/gvaartjes/highcharts-simple-sync-table/blob/master/script.js

For some reason my script is not working. It doesnt highlight the points based on the cell i click. The error I keep getting is:

> ```
> test2.html:81 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cells' of undefined
> at getCell (test2.html:81)
> at selectTableCell (test2.html:125)
> at c.select (test2.html:208)
> at highcharts.src.js:2440
> at g.fireEvent (highcharts.src.js:2445)
> at c.firePointEvent (highcharts.src.js:28098)
> at c.select (highcharts.src.js:41310)
> at test2.html:146
> at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
> at updateSelectionOfSeriesPoint (test2.html:140)
> ```

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/8.1.2/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/8.1.2/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/8.1.2/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<style>
.chart-outer {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 2em auto;
}
#myChart {    
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 2em;
  min-width: 380px;
}
.highcharts-data-table table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  background: white;
  min-width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
.highcharts-data-table td, .highcharts-data-table th, .highcharts-data-table caption {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
.highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even), .highcharts-data-table thead tr {
  background: #f8f8f8;
}
.highcharts-data-table td:hover {
  background: #eff;
}
.highcharts-data-table td.selected {
  background-color: tomato;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid;
}

.highcharts-data-table caption {
  border-bottom: none;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {

'use strict';
    /*global Highcharts*/

    /* DEMO for showing how to synchronize selected points in the chart by highlighting
     * the table cells and vice versa.
     *
     * TODO: toggle hiding series through the legend, recreates the table. Then the variables holding the elements are lost. 
     * Legend click is now disables
     */

    /**
     *  Utility to convert HTMLCollection into array
     * @param {HTMLCollection} nodes 
     * @returns {Array}
     */
    const htmlCollectionToArray = (nodes) => Array.prototype.slice.call(nodes);

    /**
     * Function for getting the cell corresponding the point selected in teh chart
     * @param {int} trIdx : Index for the array of table rows
     * @param {int} idx : Index of the Tabel cell we're interested in
     * @returns {HTMLTableCellElement}
     */
    const getCell = (trIdx, idx) => {
        let rows = document.querySelectorAll("#highcharts-data-table-0 tbody tr");

        return rows[trIdx].cells[idx]
    }

    // attach eventlistener to array of HTML elements
    const attachEventListenerToElements = (elementsArr, eventName, listener) => {
        elementsArr.forEach(elem => elem.addEventListener(eventName, listener))
    }

    // get the array of headers in the HTML table
    const getHHeaders = () => htmlCollectionToArray(
        document.querySelectorAll("#highcharts-data-table-0 thead th")).map(x => x.innerHTML);
    const getVHeaders = () => htmlCollectionToArray(
        document.querySelectorAll("#highcharts-data-table-0 tbody th")).map(x => x.innerHTML);
    let vHeaders, hHeaders;

    /**
     * Pass in a table cell element from the header of the table and retrieve all cell for this columns.
     * Loop over all rows and retrieve for every row the cell for the selected column by index. Modify the array with reduce
     * @param {HTMLTableCellElement} elem
     * @returns {Array<HTMLTableCellElement>}
     */
    const getTableCellsForColumn = (elem) => {
        // Get the cells in the row except for the first cell containing category label
        let cellsInRow = htmlCollectionToArray(document.querySelectorAll('#highcharts-data-table-0 tr')).slice(1);
        // build array with cells for index in every row
        return cellsInRow.reduce((acc, curr) => {
            let c = curr.children.item(elem.cellIndex);
            acc.push(c);
            return acc;
        }, []);
    }

    /**
     * Function for hilighting a table cell corresponding a selected datapoint
     * in the chart 
     * @param {Point} point, Highcharts.Point 
     * @param {Boolean} selected, Is the point selected or deselected?
     */
    const selectTableCell = function (point, highlight) {
        // check the global properties, initially not set
        vHeaders = vHeaders ? vHeaders : getVHeaders();
        hHeaders = hHeaders ? hHeaders : getHHeaders();

        // find corresponding cell for datapoint
        let cell = getCell(vHeaders.indexOf(point.category),
            hHeaders.indexOf(point.series.name));
        console.log(cell);

        // remove or add the classname on the element to select/deselect the tablecell
        DOMTokenList.prototype[highlight ? 'add' : 'remove']
            .apply(cell.classList, ['selected']);
    };

    /**
     * Update the data point in the series on selecting or deselecting a table cell
     * @param {Chart} chart 
     * @param {Array} tableCellArr 
     */
    const updateSelectionOfSeriesPoint = (chart, tableCellArr) => {
        tableCellArr.forEach((cell) => {
            let cellIdx = cell.cellIndex;

            let point = chart.series[cellIdx - 1].points[cell.parentNode.rowIndex - 1];

            // contains classList selected, then deselect point and v.v.
            point.select(!cell.classList.contains('selected'), true);
        })

    }

    /**
     * selected area in chart is used to filter which series points fall within the selected area
     * Normally used to zoom in, but we return false to prevent that happening
     * @param {Event} e
     */
    function selectPointsByDrag(e) {
        // Select points
        Highcharts.each(this.series, function (series) {
            Highcharts.each(series.points, function (point) {
                if (point.x >= e.xAxis[0].min && point.x <= e.xAxis[0].max &&
                    point.y >= e.yAxis[0].min && point.y <= e.yAxis[0].max) {
                    point.select(true, true);
                }
            });
        });

        return false; // Don't zoom
    }

    /**
     * On click, unselect all points
     */
    function unselectByClick() {
        var points = this.getSelectedPoints();
        if (points.length > 0) {
            Highcharts.each(points, function (point) {
                point.select(false, true);
            });
        }
    }


var chart = Highcharts.chart('myChart', {
   chart: {
                type: 'scatter',
                events: {
                    selection: selectPointsByDrag,
                    click: unselectByClick
                },
                // necesssary to be able to select by dragging
                zoomType: 'xy'
            },
  exporting: {
    showTable: true
  },
   plotOptions: {
                scatter: {
                    lineWidth: 2,
                    dashStyle: 'dot'
                },
                series: {
                    connectNulls: true,
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    pointPadding: 0,
                    point: {
                        events: {
                            select: function (e) {
                                selectTableCell(this, true);
                            },
                            unselect: function (e) {
                                selectTableCell(this, false);
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    marker: {
                        states: {
                            select: {
                                fillColor: 'tomato',
                                borderColor: 'green'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
  series: [
  {
                name: 'A',
                data: [25,36,32,10,12],
                turboThreshold: 0,
                id: 'Results1',
                marker: {
                    symbol: 'circle'
                },

            },
            {
                name: 'B',
                data: [10,20,30,40,50],
                turboThreshold: 0,
                id: 'Results2',
                marker: {
                    symbol: 'circle'
                },
            },
            {
                name: 'C',
                data: [5,6,10,12,20],
                turboThreshold: 0,
                id: 'Results3',
                marker: {
                    symbol: 'circle'
                },
            }
           ]
  
 
});


        // Attach eventListeners for the table cells holding the point values
        attachEventListenerToElements(htmlCollectionToArray(
            document.querySelectorAll('#highcharts-data-table-0 td.number')), 'click', function (e) {
                console.log("Point Values Clicked: Yes");
                updateSelectionOfSeriesPoint(chart, [e.target]);
            })

        // Attach eventListeners for the category table cells
        attachEventListenerToElements(htmlCollectionToArray(
            document.querySelectorAll('#highcharts-data-table-0 th.text[scope=row]')), 'click', function (e) {
                // create array of related cells for clicked category in the table and toggle selection 
                // for these. Shift removes the first table cell in the table row.
                console.log("Table Cell Clicked: Yes");
                updateSelectionOfSeriesPoint(chart, htmlCollectionToArray(e.target.parentElement.children).slice(1));
            })

        // Attach eventListeners for the cells selected by column click
        attachEventListenerToElements(htmlCollectionToArray(
            document.querySelector('#highcharts-data-table-0 tr').children).slice(1), 'click', function (e) {
                console.log("Column Clicked: Yes" );
                let colCells = getTableCellsForColumn(e.target);

                updateSelectionOfSeriesPoint(chart, colCells);
            })

$('#update').on('click', function() {
  var data1 = [60,50,40,30,20];

  chart.series[0].update({
    data: data1
  });
});


});
</script> 

<div id="myChart" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<button id="update">Update</button>
</html>
```

I am trying to get the above working similar to the URL i found. so if you click on one of the table cells or you click on a point it highlights either on the chart or table. You will be able to replicate my issue with the script above.

Please note the update button updates the data so the synchorization should work as well when you click the button and the chart/table renders again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the error, in the dev console, I found that the point.category wasn't find in the vHeaders because it was an number, not a string.

Solution:

```
// find corresponding cell for datapoint
let category = point.category + '';
let cell = getCell(vHeaders.indexOf(category),
  hHeaders.indexOf(point.series.name));
console.log(cell);
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/15o0yfzp/

### EDIT

According to the comments the final version is: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/92u83zwo/

Bug exists: Click on legend A. It removes from chart. Click on column B in the table. Column C gets highlighted in the table. But the points from B get highlighted on the chart
[image]

---

### EDIT 2

Demo with the fixed issue described above: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tjn8qgvz/

Comment: Yep this fixes it but once you click the update button this stops working again. For some reason the functionality stops working after the click of the button

Comment: Your update redraws the table which means that the previous listeners attached to the table HTML elements don't exist on the new elements. You need to attach them again, see: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9m2vxaoj/

Comment: This works well but also noticed when you click on one of the series in the legend e.g. 'A' it removes from the chart and table which is what I expect. But then when you click on the table the functionality also stops working. How/Where do I attach the listeners again for this as well? I am guessing it redraws the table each time you click on the legend so the previous listeners no longer exist. But not sure where in the code to attach these listeners again for this functionality to work in this secnario?

Comment: @RA19 good point! I think that a better place for those functionalities will attach them inside the render callback which triggers after each chart redraw. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/68t142hd/ API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

Comment: When I load your latest demo JSFIDDLE on load the functionality has stopped working. It seems to highlight the points and dissapears instantly. The table cells dont go red when you click anymore. If you click on a cell/column the functionality no longer works. But this used to work in your previous jsfiddle? Also the legend issue, it highlights the table but in your demo it doesnt mark the points on the highchart that you selected? If you Control + F5 your page you should see and replicate what I am seeing. It doesnt seem to always happen but when I refresh I am seeing these issues.

Comment: Does the same happen for you in your demo? I think its the render() causing it

Comment: @RA19, yes it does. My mistake. After additional debugging, I think that this is my final version? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fe3wL194/

Comment: Thanks for debugging. Still seeing a bug. If you click the legend 'A' and 'B' you should only see 'C' on the chart. Now if you click on the table the cell gets highlighted. But the points are still not. So there is still some issue with the listeners in this scenario? Is the same happening on your end?

Comment: Just so you know I have to press Control + F5 to see this issue happen. So if you give that a try you might be able to replicate. Any ideas?

Comment: @RA19, please test it: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/92u83zwo/ I did some changes in the `selectTableCell` and `updateSelectionOfSeriesPoint` functions.

Comment: Still a bug somehwere:

Replication details:
1. Run code
2. Click on legend 'A'
3. Highlight column B in the table but it highlights Column C in the table although the points on the chart are highlighted correctly.

Again you might have to hit Cntrl F5 + Refresh. I believe its because the index has probably changed my guess? Because column C is now index 2. And column B was index 2 before we took A away from the chart/table
Can you advise?

Comment: I have added an image to show you what I mean above! Hope this helps in replicating

Comment: Sorry, but in this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/92u83zwo/ it works fine. I cannot replicate the issue.

Comment: Ok can u try this in ur demo:

1. Click A on the table to highlight the column. Then unclick the column A to unhighlight
2. Then click A on the chart legend to remove from the legend and chart
3.  Then click B column on table to highlight. you should C it highlights column C and not B

I have replicated it again on your demo.
Does this happen for you?

Comment: @RA19 Yep, I got it. Check this demo plz: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tjn8qgvz/

Comment: Perfect - Thank you!